# Cisco 2911 RAM memory upgrade

Tags: cisco-isr

Does anyone knows what kind of DDR2 memory goes to DIMM0 slot in Cisco 2911 router? I tried with 512 Mb and 1 Gb with 533, 677, 800 MHz, nothing will work. It say Verification not passed.

Comment: You order the DRAM from Cisco: `MEM-2900-5123MB=` for 512 MB, `MEM-2900-1GB=` for 1 GB, or `MEM-2900-2GB=` for 2 GB. You add the `=` on the end to order it as a spare, rather than as part of the device build.